# How to translate this Silverlight control into HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in the process of converting a Silverlight app into a standard Web app (ie all HTML, CSS and JavaScript via jQuery 1.4.4). I'm not the most experienced when it comes to web development, so I am wondering what would be the best way to convert this custom Silverlight control into a web equivalent?

[image]

It boils down to just being a fancy radio button group. The user can click on any type, and only one type can be selected at a time. For the web equivalent, it needs to set a value that will get POSTed to the server.

For now I am just using a standard `<select>` tag which is of course functional and doesn't require JavaScript (which is nice), but ultimately is not going to fly. I will place a `<select>` inside of a `<noscript>` tag to allow non-js people to still be functional.

Can anyone recommend a good approach for tackling this? Any existing plugins/controls out in the wild I could take advantage of?

(I am using ASP.NET MVC 3, but I don't think that's very relevant here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a <ul> and make the selections a <li>.  Styling is easy enough to apply to that, and there are tons of samples online.

Place a click on the li using jQuery to disable.  If you are going to disable other selections, you should also include a reset/clear type function to they can choose again in case they made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Think of them as an array of buttons. When one is clicked, all others are unselected. Draw a rectangle around the one that was clicked and set a hidden form field equal to the value you expect when the form is submitted.